# catkin_add_gtest usage

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, [turtlebot-description](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/hydro/turtlebot_description) package has a CMakeLists as below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(turtlebot_description)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS urdf xacro)

catkin_package(
   CATKIN_DEPENDS urdf xacro
)

install(DIRECTORY robots
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
install(DIRECTORY meshes
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
install(DIRECTORY test
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
install(DIRECTORY urdf
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}_test_urdf test/test_urdf.cpp)
```

During the build, I get an error message as below:

```
| CMake Error at /media/Build/next/build/tmp/sysroots/duovero/usr/share/catkin/cmake/test/tests.cmake:17 (message):
|   catkin_add_gtest() is not available when tests are not enabled.  The CMake
|   code should only use it inside a conditional block which checks that
|   testing is enabled:
| 
|   if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
| 
|     catkin_add_gtest(...)
| 
|   endif()
```

It's obvious that the unit test should be only called when testing is enabled. However, the last commit on this code was 7 months ago. I am sure some would have caught the error by now. So I began looking for the correct use case for this macro, and the ROS doc doesn't mention much about it. Can someone verify that it indeed needs to check whether testing is enabled?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153881/catkin_add_gtest-usage/) by [Adam YH Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2738/adam-yh-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Confirmed; that is the correct use of catkin_add_gtest()

You should open this as a bug against the turtlebot_description package.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adam YH Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2738/adam-yh-lee/) on 2014-04-17**:
great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING was a late addition to catkin, and not every package has been updated to wrap their tests with the if/endif block. File a bug report, or create a pull request (preferred!).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adam YH Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2738/adam-yh-lee/) on 2014-04-17**:
Thanks, I created a pull request =)